# 3MF file openable but does not appear to be human readable XML

Tags: xml, human-readable

The following 3MF file is openable and printable as a 3D object. I understand that the 3MF file is supposed to be human readable XML, but hen I open in a text editor it all appears to be compressed (random nonhuman readable characters). I have tried opening with string converter but no avail (https://coderstoolbox.net/string/#!encoding=xml&action=decode&charset=us_ascii).

Any insights most welcome. Thanks.

File when opened in a text editor is:

PK   ÊP(W        ?     [Content_Types].xmlUT
|eúdå eå eux         …]jÃ0„¯"öµØrS(¥ØÎCÓž =À"¯ˆ´Ò:¤·ï:)-”Bggv>˜v  Þœ)—%r÷u†ØÅaá©ƒ÷ã[õû¾=~$*F£:˜EÒ³µÅÍ°Ô1«3ÆPTæÉ&t'œÈîšæÑºÈB,•lÐ·qõb^/z¾a3ùæåÜX`J~q(êÛ3¿(Õ¡ÖÏk¦ÌK*w cÿD„8ÿ‡~z†€¼ŽèdÍ:E¥z+ø&Øë"ý'PK¢—óâÂ   ?  PK   ÊP(W             *rels/.relsUT
|eúdå eå eux         eÉ
Â0†*%ÌÝLkADšö"‚W©’é‚ÍB’Š¾½Q,^†™ï_êöafv§'g”¼ FV9=ÙAÀµ;möÐ6õ…f™òG'YFl0¦äˆQddäÎ“Í—Þ#S^Ã€^ª›·E±Ãð«kMÖÉ0P€Õ+mœ¦™&°³Ù¬{zú³5“
.º>qåÌ›•vé¥JKÈ²sYaQ~5aSãªMóPKØ÷Wl¯     PK   ,X-W        D     3D/3dmodel.modelUT
å eä eä eux         í\ÛrÛF}ÏWpøN‰{%Ù¡œÈô›iÕÑ%#Ë'__*\PÂŠ°
{¦õ‹Ci  vA§ýø²^eÏÝîq¹Ý,r5+ó¬ÛÜo–›¿ùÓþkQçï>´ëíC·Êž6Ëý"_/W«åºÛw»<ëÑ¬>Öv›âÏOùÝ‡,ËÚ]÷¸}ÚÝw?/Ÿl¿üÓÝï³åÃ"ï5ì¿ëz9™9,9¬ZwŸ\>êMÛ/O$áoº—ì¥—8+ÃOž}Ç—?yQÎ\Ï¯‹q2bŒ3ÎÓ1ÇË41ÑM¹›¬)„Ì)„¼ÛSü‚AÈAÅ­’2è:eH(ÃA

1Pˆ€Rü“¢Ÿû.‹içÓ¥±Ýï–}A^M•Lø*{V?ëð³^äºÿeúÊ?eæÔz5¬¯¹ëëa}Å]_
ë=w½Ö;îz7¬·ÜõvXo¸ëÍ°^“ë›àÏ2€Ž  ‚‹Ô$µ&ÁIŠŽ ‚›@G):€®Rt, d¥£ˆ@WEÇCá| [£„`ø¶BÁp­G)Áð¬C9Áp¬EIÁð«AYÁp«FiÁ`¹R81‘+£Ä Nºš)ƒŽ¶r81èp+‹ƒŽ·281è€+ã,âí|êÒÎO{óv>ôóSí½oïãGmÜzªã5ùè¯µ¯5ZØF›ºjÜd 9UY©ÒWõ9ã×”œQá´œÑÜërÑy²ÝsÍ¶5×½“àœkÁJˆÕ5ß$P'îönæ ®J×Ô¥AÇëDºÈ¢xûÃv´wF×ÊÖ èxDÃ(ðè:‡W
J°çª‡t5d·R1æ—BRT<—sL¸&žËAagñ\Î±¥ð0–£n+‡„9·Zs–·:ëöX½1eŠ¡T-”*…B•P¨
ÕA¡2ø:¼"-¡PG(ÔÊôƒ2í L7(ÓÊô‚bÌCé$Tú„*ŸPá“©{2eO¦êÉ½·f^$F¤ïjû„º>™¦O¦ç“iùd:>¡ý¯ÔöWj÷+µù•Úû
m}…v¾B_¡}ïÛSðÿSÀ›ÍùJ
YÃa»gOÇ© Ð°çV0ø…9TÃm†ùŠfm˜¯öø×Á|–? óÇ— Ÿgf´
WØcGïØÁ5Æ]P#Ÿ3 òy:x&O¶Fƒ+þä†c´ŸÀ{¶£ ï ÐÄóS†§’G|x¤ëéduXc
*ùsf†Ò~‚»¨ÙŽD¨kž®9xZÎðTòHð+ºÔVXcäŸ<˜€ªdßvUh:Ü¡ÃmšRa¥¦Û…)„…Ä KH@8(çtq¯ØTñã5áý… Ñ-ð`‚WøZtÂ.:‚ÐA÷ ¢Z Â¢´ðK¼*1BÏr‡!š¡ –*#„ŸòªÁ ™¦Sx„ð9¦ËBsL+1-b“ _‹ásLëBsL1-     L6  ZøÓ6‚0ú9‡!Œz¬¡ WlŽéCý,!É&AŸc¦Œ 4ÇŒÂËÐ 60ÙòµX>ÇŒŽ Œ>Ø`ˆeh¼&– …Ï1ZØôYÆ¾ |Ž™:‚Ð3
†X†€&Û-|ŽÙ2‚Ð³
CCK€¸ÀdÇ×âø³:‚Ð³C=Ÿ
=ûxLÀØqUâ»:€ÀËå   Zø³u¡9fq-  Lv  Zøse¡9æ†x†8,Í_‹çsÌÁÖÎ?ûa€ð9æ|al‰+aœOŒ8?HÐÂç˜«#ã”¢ÁÆþ~„À!B‚>Ç|AhŽy…!çûÊ_}©Z_~©ú~»þ¶Ýt›}|D=~‘
‚†¿½Œï~ö»Ï›Ç¯ÛÝúp:®]Û¬œiÝÔ*§åýoe´¯³¢ÿ‡RÆXÛ¸ÌÌ´+K—zVéJé¬0R¨™ï¿3™šoœ?|à&ÚÅ­-À\ÒÚ‹ÆŠÛZ£G×ÁæÁÖ£‰Áæ[G‡FË{ö¢µ#
ÊÞËæ¾gkñ-×Ê‘öÄÆ×Ê09ÖÆŽým~½¡t9vÊØv~^~¯Õq#TÇÓuåÊ'Ä¿yßà$ðQXÀ
Ûïµô$ŠƒÉïÖÔøsàÝû·ôÝ—wû³¢3e)YZÚ9þo6Ú/OËÕÃ¸t¹ïÖ'7x²í‰¿‚z;ú¾ôPžîþPKÝÈVÛv  D  PK   ÊP(W¢—óâÂ   ?             ¶    [Content_Types].xmlUT
|eúdå eå eux         PK   ÊP(WØ÷Wl¯                ¶#  _rels/.relsUT
|eúdå eå eux         PK   ,X-WÝÈVÛv  D             ¶+  3D/3dmodel.modelUT
å eä eä eux         PK        ÿ

Answer (score 1):

The fact that it starts with "PK" is a strong indication that this is a ZIP-compressed file. Uncompress it, and see if the result is human-readable XML.